# Time complexity exercise

Tags: time, complexity-theory, analysis

I'm having trouble with solving an excercise. The context is an asymptotic analysis of the running time.  There are given algorithms like Insertion Sort etc. The result should be the theta notation (asymptotic exact) for the input: {N, N-1, ..., N/2, 1, 1, 2, 3, ..., N/2}. The problem is: How can I calculate the running time? I mean, it's no problem to calculate the worst-case or best-case scenario. My problem is how to handle the inputs and how to consider them in the calculation.

Thanks for your help!

Greetings
GR

Comment: Have you tried listing the steps the program actually will take for some simple input like `(4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2)` or `(6, 5, 4, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3)`? Can you "list" the steps for the general case N?

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer. :-)
I simply count the made additions and compares. So in Insertion Sort there are n(n-1)\2 Operations. In this case the Theta is Theta(n*n).
My problem now is, how can I map this to an real input?

Comment: If you actually have counted operations for the worst-case complexity of insertion sort, then you can tell what two numbers are compared by the 10th operation for sorting the numbers 1 through 100. That is, counting operations _is_ mapping the operations to real input. It is actually a harder problem because you must also determine what input is the worst case, whereas here the input is already described for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comments:

Have you tried listing the steps the program actually will take for some simple input like (4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2) or (6, 5, 4, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3)? Can you "list" the steps for the general case N? – David K Oct 23 '14 at 16:32

First of all thanks for your answer. :-) I simply count the made additions and compares. So in Insertion Sort there are n(n-1)\2 Operations. In this case the Theta is Theta(n*n). My problem now is, how can I map this to an real input? – GR_ Oct 23 '14 at 18:31

If you actually have counted operations for the worst-case complexity of insertion sort, then you can tell what two numbers are compared by the 10th operation for sorting the numbers 1 through 100. That is, counting operations is mapping the operations to real input. It is actually a harder problem because you must also determine what input is the worst case, whereas here the input is already described for you. – David K Oct 23 '14 at 19:01